# is there anyway to get categories assigned in Photos.app to certain photo programatically?

Tags: photos.app

You can browse your photos by categories, which are somehow applied using AI and some object detection algorithms to your library photos in the background, e.g "snow" to see all photos with snow, or "bike" to see all photos containing bike.

Is there any option to tell to Photos.app via applescript / swift / whatever API to get this info programmatically?

it is done offline on the device according to:

> Photos is enabled by powerful machine learning to deliver unique
> features like Memories, Search Suggestions, and For You. Photos
> analyzes every photo in a user’s photo library using on-device machine
> learning that delivers a personalized experience for each user. And
> this analysis is designed from the ground up with privacy in mind,
> with all of the processing done on device—and the results of this
> analysis are not shared with anyone, not even Apple.

source: https://www.apple.com/ios/photos/pdf/Photos_Tech_Brief_Sept_2019.pdf